# strange behavior office 365 contact API

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office365

I'm trying to consume the Office 365 contacts api, and I got a strange response every time that I change some of the parameters...

For example, accessing the following url https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts?$top=10

I get 10 contacts, and an url to the next page https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts/?$top=10&$skip=10

Accessing the url above, I get 8 contacts and no next page url.

However, if I try to access the next page explicitly (https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts/?$top=10&$skip=20 I get 10 contacts and a next page url)

what am I doing wrong? is that a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to see if I get the same results. How many total contacts do you have in your default Contacts folder? I'm trying to figure out which behavior is wrong.

UPDATE: I tried this here and could not reproduce your results. I wonder if one of the contacts in your folder is somehow causing a processing problem. It might help to narrow down the problem if you can move the contacts that come back in your second query (?$top=10&$skip=10) to another folder and repeat your test. Do you still get the weird result?

Comment: 111 Contacts https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts/$count - The page 2 returns only 8 contacts, and no next page url. https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts/?$top=10&$skip=10

Comment: You are right, one of the contacts was causing a processing problem. I deleted all the contacts and inserted them all again, looks like that everything is working now.

Comment: I'm glad that cleared it up for you, but I'd love to investigate further if possible. Were you able to identify the specific contact? Do you still have the data, or is it gone?

Comment: It's gone, I thought that deleting all the contacts was easier than moving them one by one to another folder, so I did it. The contacts were inserted by my application, using the Outlook Services Client library. I think that I inserted some invalid contacts, but the API accepted it. Maybe the invalid contacts was causing the problem. Changing the subject, is it possible to query against O365 Lync Contacts? They appear on People App but not in the Contacts API